# Structural replace to delete an exception

Tags: java, refactoring, intellij-idea, replace, structural-search

I want to delete an exception that should have never existed. I can not find the pattern that allows the deletion in the method declarations.

This code :

```
public void method1(String param) throws ShouldHaveNeverExisted{
   System.out.println("Yo");
   //... 
}

public void method2WithoutParam() throws ShouldHaveNeverExisted{
   System.out.println("Yo");
   //... 
}
```

Should be transform in :

```
public void method1(String param){
   System.out.println("Yo");
   //... 
}

public void method2WithoutParam(){
   System.out.println("Yo");
   //... 
}
```

The following pattern retrieve what I want but I can't find the correct replacement pattern.

```
class $Class$ { 
   $ReturnType$ $MethodName$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$) throws ShouldHaveNeverExisted;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Search pattern:

```
class $Class$ {
  $RetType$ $Method$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$) throws ShouldHaveNeverExisted, $ExceptionType$ {
      $SomeStatement$;
  }
}
```

Replacement pattern:

```
class $Class$ {
  $RetType$ $Method$($ParameterType$ $Parameter$) throws $ExceptionType$ {
      $SomeStatement$;
  }
}
```

The main caveat is to "Edit variables" and turn on "This variable is target of the search" checkbox for `$Method$` variable (on every try, [unfortunately](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-74094)). Also `$SomeStatement$`'s max count must be unlimited.

Then IDEA 11.0.1 does search correctly. Even for any order of exceptions in `throws` clause. And it even shows correct result on "Preview Replacement" button click.
But then actually just deletes methods found. :(

This seems to be a bug. Please, someone confirm.

BTW. If you're getting rid of this exception anywhere, why not just replace "throws ShouldHaveNeverExisted" with "" with regular "Edit\Find\Replace in Path Ctrl+Shift+R"?

Or you could just hit Del on exception's class and check "Safe delete (with usage search)".

Comment: I tried but without the first and last line, idea indicates that the pattern is not supported!!! I could resolve my problem with a Ctrl+Shift+R but I want to progress on the structural find and replace.

Comment: @Vadzim did you ever get this to work correctly? I am getting the same *preview is correct, actual replace deletes the method* behavior.

Comment: @Jarrod, I've rechecked with IDEA 13.0.2 and observed no progress since IDEA 11.